# How does one install a new custom field?

Tags: drupal, civicrm-entity, drupal-8

After adding a Custom Field on Activity -> I get this message on the status report. How does one install a new custom field?

[image]

Comment: 'installing' a custom field is a Drupal thing apparently since the docs here refer to creating custom fields, not installing - https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/creating-custom-fields/ .

Comment: See the Q and A here for the same error message  - https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/221930/44865